# how do I add a USB webcam profile to Vuforia in Unity

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I don't have an internal webcam so I have a Logitech USB camera but I'm gettin an error message in Unity "no webcam profile for your C922 Pro Stream Webcam has been found a default profile will be used" I tried opening Xcode and inserting C922 Pro Stream into the code after device name but I cant alter the document I don't have permissions. Has anyone come accross this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If u have your webcam connected , then in your

> ARCamera

, u would see an option called

> Open Vuforia Configuration

. In config. u could see another option called

> camera device

. Inside that u have to select your camera . Even i have the same camera and it worked well.

Comment: Hi Sam Thank you for responding to me. The device is showing in the camera device dropdown. But I still get the error that theres "no webcam profile" next to the webcam portion above camera device. I cant find drivers for this camera so I'm wondering if thats the issue.

Comment: Hi Sam it's working. I unplugged it and plugged it in while unity was open. It see's it now.